# Routing based on the source ip

Tags: linux, networking, vlan, route

I'm trying to configure a host in a way that the traffic is routed either via `eth0` or `vlan123@eth0`, depending on the source address used. Both interfaces have access to the whole network and both have some ip assigned.

For example: `eth0` has `1.2.3.1/24` and `vlan123` has `4.5.6.1/24`. The default gateway is set via `eth0`. How can I make sure that if:

- packet comes in to `1.2.3.1` (will arrive untagged), the response will be sent to eth0
- packet comes in to `4.5.6.1` (will arrive 802.1q tagged), the response will be sent to vlan123

Is it possible without additional routing protocols? (for example forcing via iptables)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look for information on "policy routing".  The particular use case you're looking at is covered in the [Advanced Routing and Traffic Control HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.rpdb.simple.html), as well as [elsewhere](http://www.tipsfortux.com/?p=10).